# A RegEx problem in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I could not think of a proper title. I have some data like -

```
$data = <<<EOD
<strong>
HHHHH
<strong>
TTTTT
<strong>
RRRRRRR
<strong>
EOD;
```

Basically above one is just an example. In real, the data is like -

```
<strong>Some Title</strong>
DATA
<strong>Some other Title</strong>
OTHER DATA
```

**Sample**: http://pastebin.com/cxzZWDZ8

Now I apply the following RegEx.

```
preg_match_all("%<strong>(.*?)<strong>%s", $data, $all);
```

This matches, `HHHHH` and `RRRRRRR` but I want to match `TTTTT`. How can I do this?

Comment: If that's supposed to be HTML what's the purpose of nesting `<strong>` elements in `<strong>` elements and why are there no closing tags?

Comment: @Gordon - It was just an Example. The exact data is properly formatted. Actually Its like this, <strong>Some Title</strong>DATA<strong>SOme other Title</strong> Another Data.

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML that more closely resembles the data (especially the OTHER DATA and DATA part) so we can see if Regex makes sense or if a DOM Parser is more appropriate.

Comment: @Gordon - Though My problem is solved. You still can have a look here. To what exaclty data looks like - http://pastebin.com/cxzZWDZ8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a lookahead assertion to ensure the `<strong>` is there, but isn't part of the match (so it can be part of the next match):

```
</strong>(.*?)(?=<strong>)
```

However, if what you've got is HTML, you should use an HTML parser to read it and not regex which is infamously poor at parsing HTML/XML markup. With `DOMDocument::loadHTML()`, `getElementsByName` and so on you'll have a much more reliable way of scraping page data.

Comment: @Thanks - It works. I always use HTML parser but for this task using HTML parser would result in some wastage of time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its just a typo but shouldn't your write something like:

```
preg_match_all("%</strong>(.*?)<strong>%s", $data, $all);
```

on your first exemple i dont see that you're closing the tags.. but on the "real" exemple you are.. maybe that's it